# Understanding maven project structure

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

This is my first question and it is similar to the one here [multi module maven project structure in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385741/multi-module-maven-project-structure-in-eclipse) which describes a multi-module maven project structure. My problem is that the "multi-module-maven-project" project node includes folder to other dependent modules within its node while those dependent modules still have their own separate nodes. I often need to modify existing projects in this form but the challenge is where exactly is the best place to make changes to a project of similar structure? In the "multi-module-maven-project" project node or in the respective dependent module's node?

The reason for this question is because most of the modules have configuration files, packages and Spring XML files that I often need to put into consideration while making changes as I need to edit those files or create new ones e.g "multi-module-maven-project" project may have a pom file while a dependent module may have its own pom file. It can be confusing at times, trying to find out where the setting for a particular line of code will reside

I will appreciate all responses especially those that reflect experience in the use of camel, camel-spring, maven, osgi and fuse-esb environment

Comment: Can you give an example set of pom files/project setup with the relevant settings/dependencies? That would help clarify your question so we can give better answers. 

Something with pomA.xml for project A and pomB.xml for project B which depends on A. E.g., an example along the lines of http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the way the eclipse render maven based project. It generally creates two structure. One based on master pom (parent project) and others based on individual module pom. however doing changes in any structure will reflect in the other one. As a practice I do changes in individual module folder structures and is more easy to read too.